# Generate model matrix with same columns as another table

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, xgboost

I want to use XGBoost in R to predict a new data set.

To generate the training data structure for the model, I use the code as follows to convert my data frame (which contains integers, factors and numeric data types):

```
dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data = model.matrix(frm, data = train), label = label)
```

which creates the necessary object. My model can then be trained and examined.

HOWEVER...

Now I want to use this model to predict new data. I import my new data, but when I create a DMatrix structure in a similar method to the above, I get a DIFFERENT matrix structure. This is because the new data only contains a subset of the factors of the original data and when the one-hot encoding process runs through not all necessary columns are built. If I try to predict against this new object I get the error:

> Error in predict.xgb.Booster(xgbmodel, model.matrix(frm, data =
>   newData))
>
> Feature names stored in `object` and `newdata` are different!

My question then is: how can I (efficiently) create a new DMatrix object which has the same column structure as my original training data but using the new prediction data? I would expect this to populate the one-hot columns that are dummies with zeroes in the new prediction data table.

Comment: Are you 100% sure your factor columns are all stored as factor classes in the data? I made a small example, and I got that error when treating my factors as characters, not as factors. I can post my eg if it helps

Comment: Thanks Jonny; actually I found that I had left an extra column in one data set that wasn't in the other. The above question is still valid and I believe interesting/useful for future readers (i.e. how to map a matrix structure), but the actual result is now rather academic as I've solved the problem if not the question!